# socat for sharing serial port from linux to solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, serial-port, modem, socat

I'm trying to share serial port from linux box to solaris 10 box (solaris machine don't have serial port).

While doing the same commands from linux box (modem-server) to other linux box - everything is fine.

Problems starting while using scout on solaris.

To start server on linux box I'm using:

> $ socat tcp-l:54321,reuseaddr,fork
>   file:/dev/ttyAMA0,nonblock,waitlock=/var/run/ttyAMA0.lock

On client using:

> /opt/csw/bin/socat pty,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0,waitslave
>   tcp:modem-server-ip:54321

But getting error msg:

> bash-3.00# /opt/csw/bin/socat pty,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0,waitslave
>   tcp:modem-server-ip:54321 2015/09/10 21:07:10 socat[10085] E
>   parseopts(): unknown option "waitslave"

When I remove waitslave option it starting, but /dev/vmodem0 is created as a symlink to own parent directory

> bash-3.00# ls -lad /dev/vmodem0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root
>   0 Sep 10 21:06 /dev/vmodem0 ->
>
> bash-3.00# ls /dev/vmodem0/vmodem0/vmodem0/